# Lower std.deviation of a distribution?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

How would one lower the std.dev => $\sigma$ for an arbitrary distribution?

The reason why I ask, is because I have a distribution which tend to get far above my threshold value,  and i am running out of ideas on how to keep the value low.

The thing i been doing now is decreasing the population size, values which lie 2$\sigma$ away, but I cannot continue doing that.

what else can i do?

Comment: I am not sure of what you mean, maybe you can give us more detail, but the standard deviation is an "intrinsic" aspect of a population.

Comment: My distribution is a point cloud in which some of the point may drift far away from the mean, thereby making the overall µ move and the std.dev become bigger.  At the moment i just remove those points.. but could an increasing std.dev be prevented some other way?

Comment: I have 2 point cloud could those be somehow be merged to create an overall?